# Trying to join a directory name in an Excel file to a value In another column with different lengths

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have printed out a directory of files and folders in an Excel file.  The folder name at end of the directory matches an alias in another column in an Excel file.

I am trying to join them together using a right join.  This is Access with the Excel files as linked tables and I am trying to list the directories according to their alias in the one file.

When I try to get the `Len` of the values in one column and put that in the query I am getting a syntax error join error.

Here is the query.  I don't know if I need to use substrings?

```
SELECT [General Acccounts].[Account #], [General Acccounts].[Account Name], 
[General Acccounts].[Customer Alias], [General Acccounts].[Start Date]
FROM EOM_On_Hand_Counter LEFT JOIN [General Acccounts] ON 
Right(EOM_On_Hand_Counter.DirectoryName,)(len([General Accounts].[Customer 
Alias])) = [General Acccounts].[Customer Alias]
GROUP BY [General Acccounts].[Account #], [General Acccounts].[Account Name], [General Acccounts].[Customer Alias], [General Acccounts].[Start Date];
```

You can see I want to join the right hand side of the directory name to the customer Alias value in the general accounts table because they match.  When I use the `Len` function in Access it doesn't work within the SQL query.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the closing and opening parentheses just after comma in `Right()` function.

Comment: @Parfait tried this and it says Syntax Error In Join Operation  . I removed the ( right after the comma and did the len operator.                 `SELECT [General Acccounts].[Account #], [General Acccounts].[Account Name], [General Acccounts].[Customer Alias]
FROM [General Acccounts] INNER JOIN EOM_On_Hand_Counter ON [General Acccounts].[Customer Alias] = right(EOM_On_Hand_Counter.DirectoryName,Len([General Accounts].[Account Name]))
GROUP BY [General Acccounts].[Account #], [General Acccounts].[Account Name], [General Acccounts].[Customer Alias]`

Comment: Please provide example data of both tables so we can reproduce.

Comment: @Parfait `EOM_On_Hand_Counter.DiretoryName = S:\admins\EOM\Tyco / [General Accounts].[Customer Alias] = Tyco`  I am trying to match the length of the customer alias to right of the directory Name.  Since they are both 4 I need the length of the Customer alias. `EOM_On_Hand_Counter.DirectoryName = S:\admins\EOM\Sprint / [General Accounts].[Customer Alias] = Sprint` So you can see i want to match the right six characters on that one. Basically the customer Alias is the same right characters of the end Directory Name.

Comment: Please edit post with data. It is hard to read in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since the directory name is a fixed length s:\admins\EOM\ I can do the following:

```
SELECT [General Acccounts].[Customer Alias], 
EOM_On_Hand_Counter.DirectoryName, EOM_On_Hand_Counter.FileName, 
EOM_On_Hand_Counter.DateCreated
FROM [General Acccounts] INNER JOIN EOM_On_Hand_Counter ON [General 
Acccounts].[Customer Alias]  = mid(EOM_On_Hand_Counter.DirectoryName,15,20)
GROUP BY [General Acccounts].[Customer Alias], 
EOM_On_Hand_Counter.DirectoryName, EOM_On_Hand_Counter.FileName, 
EOM_On_Hand_Counter.DateCreated;
```

Leaving the length at the end 20 compensates for the longest customer alias and the query returns what I need it to.